# input関数の初期値(defval)について

Tags: pine-script

input関数の初期値(defval)について、request.financialのOPER_INCOMEを参照し入力したいです。
どのようにコードを書けばよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

出来ないようですね。
パラメータに使える値は const 型でコンパイル時に一意に決まっている必要があるそうです。

こちらの記事とかマニュアルにそうした記述があります。

input関数の一種で別のメソッドの記事
[input.text_area - want to use variable for defval](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75103351/9014308)
解決のチェックはされていませんが、回答に以下仕様説明と同じ内容が書かれています。

根拠となるPine Scriptの仕様説明
[Input function parameters](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Inputs.html#input-function-parameters)

> The parameters common to all input functions are: `defval`, `title`, `tooltip`, `inline` and `group`. Some parameters are used by the other input functions: `options`, `minval`, `maxval`, `step` and `confirm`.
>
> All these parameters expect arguments of “const” form (except if it’s an input used for a “source”, which returns a “series float” result). This means they must be known at compile time and cannot change during the script’s execution. Because the result of `input.*()` function is always of “input” or “series” form, it follows that the result of one `input.*()` function call cannot be used as an argument in a subsequent `input.*()` call because the “input” form is stronger than the “const” form.
>
> - `defval` is the first parameter of all input functions. It is the default value that will appear in the input widget. It requires an argument of the type of input value the function is used for.

和訳

> すべての入力関数に共通のパラメータは、`defval`、`title`、`tooltip`、`inline`、`group` です。 一部のパラメーターは、他の入力関数 (`options`、`minval`、`maxval`、`step`、`confirm`) で使用されます。
>
> これらのパラメーターはすべて、「const」形式の引数を想定しています (ただし、それが「series float」結果を返す「source」に使用される入力である場合を除く)。 これは、コンパイル時にそれらを認識する必要があり、スクリプトの実行中に変更できないことを意味します。 なぜなら `input.*()` 関数の結果は常に「input」または「series」形式であり、 「input」形式は「const」形式よりも強力であるため、1つの `input.*()` 関数呼び出しの結果を後続の `input.*()` 呼び出しの引数として使用することはできません。
>
> - `defval` は、すべての入力関数の最初のパラメータです。 これは、入力ウィジェットに表示されるデフォルト値です。関数が使用される入力値のタイプの引数が必要です。